# Browser automatically downloads PHP files

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

i'm reading the book 'Node.js for PHP Developers'. I have created a NodeJS Web Server and it receives requests and gives response too. But whenever I access a PHP file to reroute it to a JS file (requirement it is), my browser automatically downloads the PHP file.

Here's my JS code, according to which it also downloads JS files(e.g. when I access localhost:1337/first.njs)

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var file = require('./first.njs');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
if(url.parse(req.url).pathname == 'first.php')
    file.serve(req, res);
else
    res.end('The file doesn\'t exist');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');

console.log('Server is running on 1337');
```

And here's my PHP file if it matters

```
<?php
  echo "ASD";
?>
```

I know it feels like a really dumb question, but I can't figure out why that happens.

Browsers tested: Chrome and Firefox.

**UPDATE**
Couldn't figure out the exact problem neither could replicate the problem - but this is my latest code if anyone wants to reroute a requested PHP file to a JS file and serve it(the JS file)

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var file = require('./first.njs');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
if(url.parse(req.url).pathname == '/first.php')
    file.serve(req, res);
else
    res.end('File not found');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');

console.log('Server is running on 1337');
```

Comment: What do you get if you access the php file directly?

Comment: You don't have PHP installed.

Comment: @Nicolas Not having apache would mean no web server that means not even a chance of getting anything (not even downloading a file).

Comment: @CharlotteDunois my PHP code

Comment: You didn't install PHP or didn't activate the apache module.

Comment: @Nicolas but I have a Web Server written in NodeJS, that listens to requests and then gives a response. My request being localhost:1337/first.php, it must not serve the PHP file as I just read the URL name through code, and then served another file. Question is then, why does it download the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if a PHP page can be rendered without actually rendering it to the page you can use an ajax request in JavaScript/jQuery.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'YOUR PHP FILE PATH',
        success: function (dataCheck) {
            // file was accessed
        }
    });
```

Inside your success function you can output that the PHP file was successfully accessed.

Comment: I have a Web Server (WAMP and XAMPP both) and am a PHP Web Developer, I just want to get the URL name whatever it is, I don't want to respond by serving a PHP file. I just want the server to print '/first.php' whenever I send a request using 'localhost:1337/first.php'.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want to happen. Please explain exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Okay. I don't want to serve a file. I just want the path to the file which is accessed. Like if I access first.php, it must respond with a string 'You accessed first.php'. It can't happen?

Comment: Ohh, I see what you are saying. How about an ajax request in jQuery that will respond if the PHP page was accessed and print our the URL that it went to?

Comment: Hmm, seems nice to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Once you get a better handle on node, you'll probably want to use expressjs, take a look at [expressjs routing](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.VERB).

```
app.get('/first.php', function(req, res){
    res.send('You accessed first.php!');
});
```

---

If you then wanted to display the php, you could use [**php-node**](https://www.npmjs.org/package/php-node) to render php in node.js.

Comment: I do not want to render PHP mate. I want this to happen -> I don't want to serve a file. I just want the path to the file which is accessed. Like if I access first.php, it must respond with a string 'You accessed first.php'. It can't happen?

Comment: @AbdussamiTayyab Ah, I believe you're looking for [routing](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.VERB)

Comment: Oh mayn, look at the update, haha never ever forget a semi-colon, bracket and a forward-slash.

Comment: Yeah thanks mate. I'm actually trying to know NodeJS because when I learnt ExpressJS it was just code copy-paste.

Comment: @AbdussamiTayyab No problem. I did the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't have Apache (or some other server) or PHP configured.  The request has to go to the PHP script first.  So you would have to hit localhost:80/file.php and then in the PHP script redirect to localhost:1337/file.js.

A better suggestion for what you want to do is actually reverse proxy from Apache to Node.js and then have Node.js read the path.

Comment: Kindly refer to the comment in @Nicholas 's answer. And the book does it, it works, it describes how his code did work. Mine doesn't work.